# Override Features in extended Specs

Tags: spock, geb

I'm attempting to setup a testing scenario where I can publish a JAR of tests that will run the same sets of tests 95% of the time but there will be 5% of the tests that need to either override or stop a feature in the parent class.  Is it possible to override parent specifications?

```
class ParentSpec extends Specification {
    def "goto home page"() {
        given:
        to NormalHomePage

        expect:
        at NormalHomePage
    }
}
```

... in a separate project that brings in the dependency for the ParentSpec

```
class ChildSpec extends ParentSpec {
    @Override
    def "goto home page"() {
        given:
        to SpecificHomePage

        expect:
        at SpecificHomePage
    }
}
```

Is there something that I can do to either do this or simulate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overriding feature methods isn't currently supported. With some effort, it would be possible to write an extension that skips the "super" method.

Comment: Just for anyone who finds this question. It looks like the original question poster ended up taking this advice and implemented his own spock extension. This can be found here: https://github.com/mike-ensor/spock-feature-override-extension